# How To Edit Index Page In Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I want to edit the html of content area in index page in magento. I have tried to do many times but i failed. I am unable to find the index.phtml file in the theme.

```
Porto Theme\app\design\frontend\smartwave\porto\template\page\html
```

this is my root directory of the theme

for example this is my html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**I want to do some changes here in the index page**

**[image: magento directory]**

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to put html on your home page you can do it from easy way. in porto theme there were several homepages you have to found active home page (may be it's url-key "home") and edit them by clicking that record.

**Steps**

1. login to adminpanel
2. select CMS > pages
3. choose a page url-key with home page or your active home page
4. you are now edit mode of the selected page
5. select Content Tab from left Tab
6. put your html code in Content box
7. save and catch clear
8. done.